# How long of a sheitel is too long?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, hair-covering

Is there a length of sheitel that would be considered too long and inappropriate for a married woman to wear - either halachically or from a standpoint of proper moral behavior for a Jewish woman?

Comment: Why would you think such a length exists? AFAIK it doesn't (outside of possible local customs). Do you know of important hair lengths from other contexts, perhaps? Are there formal maxima on other pieces of clothing that you know of? Please [edit] your question to make it seem less like "do purple elephants with orange stripes exist?"

Comment: @DoubleAA See [here](http://imgur.com/a/yzepa) and [here](http://imgur.com/a/vQcs6).

Comment: @ada that entirely supports everything I said

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't say it didn't. Another silly question would be *how tight is too tight clothing?* or, being that one should keep his clothing clean, *how clean is clean enough?*

Comment: @ada or how many pinstripes on a suit is too many? or polka dots on socks?

Answer (score 3):

From a strict halachic perspective, if "foreign hair" counts as a covering, then it would work even if it's very long. (A more interesting question -- could it be so long as to be considered a "burden" [or likely to become one] rather than "clothing/adornment", which would make it prohibited to wear outside on Shabbos without an eruv? Probably not.)

Many rabbis have complained that sheitels that attract too much attention are missing the point (if still satisfying the letter of the law); I'd figure that could apply to an extremely long one. But there are no formal laws about exactly what kind of sheitel is called "attracting too much attention."

Comment: "if still satisfying the letter of the law" I'm not sure how something that "attracts a lot of attention" can possibly be considered "modest". Anything that is not modest is not proper moral behavior for a Jewish woman. I remember Rabbi Blumenkrantz a"h telling my wife, A woman is allowed to be attractive but not attracting - and you ladies know the difference!